# Ajax call not reaching Laravel controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I'm trying to update a field in the DB upon clicking on a `<a>` tag via jquery.

The following is the HTML code :

```
<a href="#" onclick="removeNumber()" id="notif-rmv" name="notif-rmv" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">

            <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>Notifications <span class="badge">{{count(auth()->user()->notifics)}}</span></a>
```

Jquery code :

```
$('#notif-rmv').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: notRmv,
            data: { _token: token}
        })

    .done(function () {

        });
});
```

route and route script :

```
<script>
        var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
        var notRmv = '{{ route('not.rmv') }}';
</script>

Route::get('/notrmv', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@notif_read_bdg',
    'as' => 'not.rmv'
]);
```

And there is an update statement in the controller which is not reached via jquery and not running.

```
    public function notif_read_bdg()
    {

        $user = Auth::user();
               $u_id = $user->id;

DB::table('notifs')->where('rec_uid', $u_id)->update(['badge_read' => 1]);
}
```

I'm suspecting the Jquery code has the problem as I'm not that good in it, so can you please let me know if there is a problem in the jquery code ?

Comment: Do you have a `POST` route for `notrmv`? Cause `method: 'POST',` does not work for `Route::get()`.

Comment: Anchor tag has one onclick method and you are again listening onclick for same with jquery click listener. Keep one of both. And inside onclick put **event.preventDefault()** to prevent default action of anchor tag or else it will try to go #url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax code you're telling jquery to make the request as a POST request, but your route is defined as a GET request. By convention, if you're updating a resource you should be using either PUT or PATCH in both places. I usually use PATCH just because it sounds more like an "update"

Ajax call as follows

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'PATCH',
    url: notRmv,
    data: { _token: token}
}).done(function () {

});
```

And your route

```php
Route::patch('/notrmv', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@notif_read_bdg',
    'as' => 'not.rmv'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you call with POST method from ajax, but in Laravel, you have only route for GET request..So, you have to change  method: 'POST'  in method: 'GET' or Route::get in Route::post.

Also you can check for errors in network tab in your browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is GET request route.
You need route for POST request.

```
Route::post('/notrmv', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@notif_read_bdg',
    'as' => 'not.rmv'
]);
```